# Image not loading from css file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have managed to display html in a UIWebView, but my problem is that the images are not displaying in my HTML, although my images, css, and javascript are all located in the same project folder.

Here is the my HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 320"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
        <script src="site.js" type="text/javascript" />
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
        <div class="player"></div>
        <div class="controller">
            <div class="search"></div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

div.player{
    width:320px;
    height:180px;
}

div.controller{
    float:left;
     width:320px;
}

div.search{
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    width:320px;
    background-image:url('search.jpg');
}
```

And, finally, my Objective-C:

```c
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [navigatorWindow loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];

    NSLog(@"%@",htmlString);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: @H2CO3 it appears you forgot to remove Xcode from the title... Fixed that for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `search.jpg` is adding to the Xcode Project. I believe that's the problem, because it is a local html file and not hosted on a server. Hope this helps.

Comment: i have dragged the file into my xcode project and is visible in the project tree. is this fine

Answer (score 0):

`background-image:url('search.jpg');` you have to give the full path of image here